# select two columns using lambda expression

Tags: c#

I have a table with several columns (clm1-clm10). The datagrid is populated with all columns as follows:

```
MyTableDomainContext context = new MyTableDomainContext();
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = context.DBTables;
context.Load(context.GetDBTablesQuery());
```

`GetDBTablesQuery()` is defined in `domainservices.cs` as follows:

```
public IQueryable<DBTable> GetDBTables()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.DBTables;
}
```

How can I displayed only two columns (e.g. clm1 and clm5) using the select lambda expression?

Comment: @JeremyCook: Is it matters in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting Many Fields From a Table using Linq and Lamda Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716337/selecting-many-fields-from-a-table-using-linq-and-lamda-expressions)

Comment: It may not, but different frameworks that have controls with the same name sometimes behave differently. Not taking that into consideration has caused me headaches in the past.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a duplicate of that.  Although the answer may ultimately be the same in many cases, trying to display information in a data grid is not the same as creating a variable.

Answer (score 15):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
GetDBTables().Select(o => new { o.clm1, o.clm5 });
```

It will result in an anonymous type.  If you want it to result in some type you have defined it could something like this:

```
GetDBTables().Select(o => new MyViewModel { clm1 = o.clm1, clm5 = o.clm5 });
```

Comment: Many thanks Jeremy, 
I believe this is what I am looking for.  
I am using an IQueryable so I m trying to return string values
Return  GetDBTables().Select(o => new MyDto { clm1 = o.clm1, clm5 = o.clm5 });

 But complains about missing domain space MyDto (I know this is a dumb Q but) how is it defined?

Comment: MyDto would be a class you have created that only has the properties you want, e.g. clm1 and clm5 in this case. Alternatively, use the [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) syntax and don't create a concrete class like MyDto unless you really need to.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this answer/extension was fantastic! Thanks Jeremy