# Using Variables for Table and Column in LINQ

Tags: database, vb.net, linq

So I am writing a VB.Net that is using LINQ to access a database.  There is one part of the program that I have been having trouble figuring out, how to access a column in a table when both values are passed as variables.

Right now I have a setup using `SqlConnection` strings and `SqlDataAdapters` to get the job done, but this is literally the only segment of my code that uses this syntax and it bothers the hell out of me.  I'd like to figure out how to change the code to a LINQ format so that I have the code base feeling more cohesive.

This is the code segment I have right now:

```
Public Function GetColumnFromTable(col As String, tbl As String) As AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim source As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("my connection string")
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return source
    End Try
    Dim query As New SqlCommand("SELECT " + col + " FROM " + tbl + "", conn)
    Dim dataSource As New DataTable
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query)
    adapter.Fill(dataSource)
    For i = 0 To dataSource.Rows.Count - 1
        source.Add(dataSource.Rows(i)(field).ToString())
    Next
    conn.Close()
    Return source
End Function
```

The code is meant to grab the rows from a specific column in a table and set them to an `AutoCompleteStringCollection` that is used as the autofill for text boxes on the GUI.  I would like to be able to change it to something like this.

```
Public FUnction GetColumnFromTable(col As String, tbl As String) As AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim source As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim query = From tbl Select col
    query.ToList().ForEach(Function(x) source.Add(x))
End Function
```

I'd like something like the above code that actually works, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716337/selecting-many-fields-from-a-table-using-linq-and-lambda-expressions

Comment: @JacobH Similar.  That is a good example of how to grab the columns when you know the table.  But want to be able to grab the columns when both what columns are needed, and the table they are in aren't known until the execution of the method.

Comment: It looks to me like if you normalised the database then you would not need to do that, but of course you could have inherited something which is not normalised and it's too much work to make it simpler to query at this stage. You could instead have one table with columns for tbl and col, and use something like `SELECT col FROM bigTable WHERE tbl = @tbl`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton How would normalizing the Database fix my problem?

Comment: @Skitzafreak The value of tbl would be a value in a column instead of the name of a table, so the value of tbl can be a parameter instead of part of the query.

Comment: @AndrewMorton So if it was properly normalized you're saying I could just reference any table in the database, and use a `Where` clause to essentially find the column in the correct table I am looking for?

Comment: @Skitzafreak I am envisaging one table for all the autocomplete strings, but maybe that doesn't make sense for the data you're working with.

Comment: @AndrewMorton not only great advice but a new vocabulary word for me!